# Can't load a local jquery.js into node.js (NPM jsdom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to load a local jquery.js into node.js NPM [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) according to the example:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var fs = require("fs");
var jquery = fs.readFileSync("c:/test/js/jquery.js", "utf-8"); // here it reads the jquery file from local disk

jsdom.env(
  "http://somewebsite.com",
  [jquery],
  function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function () {
      console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
  }
);
```

And it is giving the error bellow:

```
window.$(".detLink")[0].text
       ^

TypeError: window.$ is not a function
    at Object.done (C:\test.js:59:13)
    at C:\nodeJS\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:320:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

It only works if I retrieve the jquery from some online CDN:

```
jsdom.env(
  "http://somewebsite.com",
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"], // here it reads the jquery from CDN
  function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function () {
      console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
  }
);
```

The local jquery is exactly the same from the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using `cheerio`, which is a "fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server" : https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Example use case:

```
return request-promise(options)
    .then( (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
            // do something 
        }
    })
    .catch( (err) => { console.log(`Url request error:  ${err}, ${url}`); });
```

`request-promise` is an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the opposite. I don't want to retrive the jquery from online sources, I want it to be loaded from local.

Comment: And why wouldn't your needs be satisfied if you used `cheerio`?

Comment: Why would I need cheerio in the first place? The point of this question is to load jquery **LOCALLY** not remotely. Got it?